# how can i use inject my own so by frida when there is a string type?

Tags: android, shared-libraries, hook, frida

i hooked the native function dlopen in libc.so,and i want to use it.i find i need to new a nativefunction and set the arguments type like this:

1. new NativeFunction (address,returntype,[...,abi]) and the native
   function like this:
2. void* dlopen(const char*,int ) i donot know how to choose the type to match const char*,i write this :
3. var fun=new NativeFunction(_dlopen,'pointer',['pointer','int'])
   and my so's path is '/data/local/tmp/***.so' so i write this:
4. var str='/data/local/tmp/***.so'
5. fun(str,1)

but the console gives me an error that  :

invalid argument value
at /[5]
what should i do ? can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Module.load`
https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#module-load

If you want to inject a module instead of another module you can do something like this

```js
        Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, "dlopen"), {
            onEnter: function(args) {
                if ( args[0].readUtf8String().includes(excludeModuleName) ) {
                  Module.load('/data/local/tmp/custom.so');
                  // now we need to fail the original dlopen
                  // we can do something like this.. or replace the return value..
                  // maybe later i'll edit with a better solution ;)
                  args[0].writeUtf8String('...');
                }
            }
        });
```

To answer your question in comment

> how do i start my function in the so injected by frida?is there some
> methods?

```js
Module.load('/data/local/tmp/a');
var func_ptr = Module.findExportByName('a', 'function_name');
// wrap with NativeFunction(pointer, return_value, [list_of_arguments])
// lets assume your function gets a string and an int
// function_name(string a1, int a2)
var f = new NativeFunction(func_ptr, 'pointer', ['pointer', 'int']);
// invoking the fuction
f(Memory.allocUtf8String("abcd"), 3);
```

Comment: yes，i use Module.load successfully inject my so.but i have another question ,how do i start my function in the so injected by frida?is there some methods?

Comment: @zgy0x01 edited answer, if helped, approve by marking V

Comment: hi，i'm sorry to have another question on frida.i want to pass a native function ,but i find if i add return in onenter,it doesnt work,how can i do it?

Comment: you should probably open a new question

Comment: Is `/data/local/tmp/a` is path where frida-server is running?

Comment: yes but not necessarily, it where the `.so` is located